# how to run binary file in composer.json?

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php, lumen

I want to run a binary file with a composer

```
"bin": [
    "bin/migration"
]
```

> error: 'migration' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: add the extension file

Comment: What do you mean by "run a binary file with composer"? What have you tried to debug the problem?